# Analyse der Sätze

Tags: interpretation

"Dabei stellte sich heraus, dass die Personen, die vorher in einem Fragebogen angegeben hatten, Emotionen stärker zu beachten, **auch die auf den Fotos ausgedrückten Gefühle** besser identifizieren konnten. Die anderen aber, die angegeben hatten, dass sie Gefühle weniger beachten, konnten **auch die Gefühle auf den Fotos** nicht so gut wiedererkennen."

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen dem Voldschen Satz?

Ich weiß nicht, dass was die Bedeutung von "die" im Satz "auch die auf den Fotos ausgedrückten Gefühle" ist.

*Auch die Gefühle auf den Fotos ausgedrückten*, ist falsch?

Comment: Was bedeutet "Voldsche Satz"? Ich vermute, es handelt sich um einen Tippfehler, aber ich habe keine Vorstellung, was gemeint sein könnte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ich weiß nicht, dass was Bedeutung von "die" in Satz "auch die auf den Fotos ausgedrückten Gefühle" ist.

In diesem Satzteil ist "die" der bestimmte Artikel für "Gefühle".

(Ich würde das "auch" übrigens nicht zum relevanten Satzteil hinzurechnen - "die auf den Fotos ausgedrückten Gefühle" ist der relevante Ausschnitt.)

> auch die Gefühle auf den Fotos ausgedrückten, ist falsch?

Genau, das wäre eine falsche Wortstellung - "auf den Fotos ausgedrückten" hat hier die Funktion eines Adjektivs, die im Deutschen dem Substantiv vorangestellt sind, auf das sie sich beziehen.

Vergleiche mit einem einfacher strukturierten Fall:

- "die guten Gefühle": richtig
- "die Gefühle guten": falsch

Answer (score 1):

Das *die* ist schlicht ein Artikel: die Gefühle.

- auch die Gefühle besser identifizieren konnten
- auch die ausgedrückten Gefühle besser identifizieren konnten
- auch die auf den Fotos ausgedrückten Gefühle besser identifizieren konnten
- auch die nachts im Wald, in einer großen, von einem internationalen Verlag veranstalteten Ausstellung, auf den Fotos ausgedrückten Gefühle besser identifizieren konnten